# Kissing tzitzit for full shma during "leolam yehey"

Tags: halacha, tzitzis, shacharis-morning-prayer, shema, kissing

If one begins shacharit near sof zman kriat shema and is concerned that he not be able to say shema before sof zman kriat shema, he is supposed to say "full shema" during leolam yehey in the begining of shacharit. In this situation, should he kiss tzitzit and/or tefilin and should he say "emet" at the end?

EDIT: Hacham Gabriel answered the last part of the question. I'm still looking for an answer to the first part (Do you kiss tzitzit & tefilin or not?).

Comment: Please consider adding some more information to your question. For example, explain more about why someone would say Shema at that time, where we say "Leolam Yehey", etc. Try to add as much detail to your question as possible.

Comment: I learned from my rov that when reciting Shema to be yoitze krias Shema, one should be stringent to avoid hefsek and not kiss tzitzis or after touching tefilin.  I also learned that one should always add emes when reciting the full Shema.  If I anyone knows a source I would post this as an answer.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14881

Answer (score 5):

According to Yalkut Yosef 58:2

> ובתוך זמן קריאת שמע צריך לקרוא את כל הג' פרשיות, ולא רק את הפרק הראשון

One must read all three Parashiot.

Yalkut Yosef 61:17

> ויחיד שקורא קריאת שמע, בשחרית או בערבית, או בקריאת שמע שעל המטה, יסיים בשלש תיבות אלו:''ה' אלהיכם אמת'', כדי להשלים רמ''ח תיבות בקריאת שמע שהן כנגד רמ''ח איבריו של אדם.

One should say Emet at the end, even of this one.

I'm still looking,BH BN I'll be back for part I didn't answer.

Comment: I am quite certain that these halachot precede Chacham Ovadyah, so let's try to find sources that come before him...

Comment: @AdamMosheh you mean from the footnotes?

Comment: @AdamMosheh this is from the online version, and for some reason my set of Yalkut Yosef at home I can't find it.