# Covering eyes for leolam yehey

Tags: halacha, shacharis-morning-prayer, shema, parts-of-the-body

[As in this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14664/5), if you begin "leolam yehey" at the beginning of shacharit near the end of the time for reciting shema, and you may not otherwise recite it in time, you are supposed to recite a full shema there at "leolam yehey".

In such a case, should you cover your eyes when you say shema in "leolam yehey..." in the beginning of shacharit?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14664

Comment: More detail makes a better question: e.g., what this "leolam yehey" you refer to is, or why you might think we should cover our eyes there.

Comment: Can someone please explain the downvote...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Ben Ish Hai I Miqes (S"Q 7)

> כשיגיע לק"ש קודם פרשת התמיד יזהר לומר פסוקים שמע ישראל ובשכמל"ו בכונה גדולה כמו ק"ש דיוצר, הן בסגירות עיניו

When one reaches the Qeriat Shema prior to Parashat HaTamid he should be scrupulous to say Shema and Baruch Shem with great intention like the Keriat Shema of Yoser (Ohr). Including closing the eyes...

Answer (score 5):

As the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch implies in 17:3, **covering one's eyes is done to help one concentrate.**

Since in "*leolam yehey*" one usually is not fulfulling the Mitzva of saying Shma, there's no reason to cover one's eyes.

However, if one is saying the full Shma in "*leolam yehey*" due to time constraints, then one should have to cover one's eyes.

Comment: Although what you say about "covering one's eyes is done to help one concentrate" may be true, I don't see it implied in the text of Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 17:3. It says there that it is customary to say the first verse aloud to to arouse one's intent/concentration, then that the right hand is put over the eyes, all in a list of other dos and don'ts for saying the first verse that aren't necessarily related to concentrating.