# Source in Hazal for holding sisith during qiryath shema`?

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, tzitzis, provenance, chazal

Is there a source in *Hazal* specifically for grasping the (front) two *ssissith* during the recitation of the *shema`*?

If not, where does it stem from and what is the purpose?

Thanks. Kol tuv.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8817, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17508. Also related, but to a lesser degree: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15175, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22580, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14664, and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6737.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/22584/603

Comment: @Menachem That's not a source in Hazal, just some rishonim and acharonim. Did I miss something? Kol tuv.

Comment: @Maimonist, re your comment, didn't you ask "If not, where does it stem from and what is the purpose?"?

Comment: @msh210 Yes, but I would have expected something akin to "There is no source AFAIK in Hazal, but..." Kol tuv.

Comment: Did you ask about holding 2 specifically as opposed to 4?

Comment: I guess. What I saw in the Rishonim was that it was part of the *misswah* of *tallith* to hold two in front while two are behind the back. I saw this inany sources attributed to the Yerushalmi, but I looked in every edition I could find and did not find the statement anywhere but in *pirushim* such as the *Qorban HaEidhah* et al. Kol tuv.

Answer (score 2):

I shall excerpt some items from [this Beurei Hatefila article](http://www.beureihatefila.com/files/The_Custom_To_Kis_One_s_Tzitzis_During_Kriyas_Shema.pdf) that addresses the origin of the custom to kiss the tzizit during *Kri'at Shema*. Oviously, kissing them involves holding them, so the article addresses specifically your question and more:

Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 24:2

> It is a Mitzvah to hold one’s Tzitzit in one’s left hand and on top of
>   one’s heart while reciting Kriyat Shema. We find a hint for this
>   practice in the words of the verse: V’Hayu Ha’Divarim H’Ailah etc. Al
>   Livavecha (on your heart). There are those whose practice it is to
>   look at one’s Tzitzit when they recite the words: Oo’Rieetem Oto and
>   to then touch the Tzitzit over one’s eyes. This is a nice custom and a
>   demonstration of a love for Mitzvot. Ramah: Some have the custom to
>   kiss their Tziztit after looking at them. All these practices are
>   demonstrations of a love for Mitzvot.

Also, see *Magen Avraham* (mentioned in the article) for a somewhat more specific instruction.

Mordechai Succah 563 (excerpt):

> If a minor knows how to put on a Talis, his father should buy him a
>   Talis; the purpose is not to fulfill the Mitzvah of Tzitzit but
>   instead it is so that the boy can throw two Kanfot to his back and
>   keep two Kanfot in front of him and hold the Tzitzit in the proper way
>   while reciting Kriyat Shema

Hagahot Maimoniyot on Ramba"m Laws of Tzitzit ch. 3 law 11:

> Al Livavecha. On my left hand, I tie my Tephilin and in that hand I
>   hold my Tzitzit while reciting Kriyat Shema. This demonstrates that
>   the Mitzvah is fulfilled by holding the Tzitzit in one’s left hand
>   opposite one’s heart while reciting Kriyat Shema.

But, there is also an opposing viewpoint!

Sefer Ha'Eshkol, laws of prayer, p. 38b:

> Rav Notrani held: One who holds his Tzitzit while reciting Kriyat
>   Shema is displaying haughtiness.